# Accessibility for HTML reading out link and not label?

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

Hi I have the following question in regards to accessibility, I'm using JAWS screen reader software to test my code and I have the following issue:

JAWS reads out the heading label for the category, but it doesn’t represent the category and its repeating twice. The software says "Create case dash link";"Create case dash link".

The software should read should be Ask a question"

Please advise, my HTML is below

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<article class="icon-feature icon-feature--first">
<a class="icon-feature__link" href="/support/create-case/"></a>

<div class="icon-feature__icon bg--blue-primary" style="height: 150px;">
<a class="icon-feature__link" href="/support/create-case/">

<span class="icon icon--signs"></span>

<div class="imghoveropacity">
<img class="img-fluid" title="Ask a question" src="/Illustration__SS_illo_Ask_a_question" alt="Ask a question" width="150px" height="150px">
</div>
</a>
</div>
<a class="icon-feature__link" href="/support/create-case/">
<h3 class="icon-feature__title">Ask a question</h3>
 </a>
<p class="icon-feature__excerpt">Submit an enquiry</p>
</article></div>
```

Comment: If a link contains no text, the function or purpose of the link will not be presented to the user. This can introduce confusion for keyboard and screen reader.At line 3 you are using empty anchor tag.

Comment: @Pratik how will I fix this?

Comment: Either you provide text in anchor tag or use attribute 'aria-label' to describe purpose of anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAWS is right, there's nothing to read from its perspective. Well, almost nothing.
If you want JAWS with default settings to read your links, they should have either A) *link text*, i.e., something meaningful between `<a>` and `</a>`, or B) The `aria-label` attribute that should not be empty.

You have here:

```
<a class="icon-feature__link" href="/support/create-case/"></a>
```

This link contains *nothing* to JAWS' eyes. I mean, nada. The easiest way to fix this is to add an `aria-label` attribute, like this:

```
<a class="icon-feature__link" href="/support/create-case/" aria-label="Ask Question"></a>
```

Then JAWS would know what to read when the focus lands on that link. Otherwise, as it is a link, so a priority piece of data that *must* be announced somehow, it tries to get at least something and reads the (relative) URL, that's why you hear "Create Case".
The other link is a more cumbersome case. You have a link, a `div` inside it, and an `img` inside that `div`. Here JAWS is also confused because the *link text* is blank again, so it probably should read the `alt` attribute of the image, but this image is in another `div`, so it is not sure if the `div` should be read as the link contents. Oh yes, and there is an empty `span` also, and it is the first element of the link, so even more confusion arises.
If I were you, I'd also simply add an `aria-label` *if* you need that link to be read, too. And if the `span` is not needed and is only for decoration purposes, hide it from JAWS' view, otherwise you also will get some hard-to-notice troubles. After that, if you hear "Ask Question" twice on that link, hide the `div` with the image, you don't need it anymore (this last point is to be discussed, needs to be tested more thoroughly):

```
<a class="icon-feature__link" href="/support/create-case/" aria-label="Ask Question">
<span class="icon icon--signs" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<div class="imghoveropacity" aria-hidden="true">
<img class="img-fluid" title="Ask a question" src="/Illustration__SS_illo_Ask_a_question" alt="Ask a question" width="150px" height="150px">
</div>
</a>
```